# {} vs. () initialization of a class member

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, initialization

I do not understand why the following code compiles ?

```
struct A{ A(int); }; struct B{ A a{1}; };
```

but this does not:

```
struct A{ A(int); }; struct B{ A a(1); };
```

**error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant**

Is there some reason the compiler does not accept the second form? I am aware of the most vexing parse ambiguiy, but I do **not** think this question is related.

*EDIT*: As Bo explains in the comments below, I was wrong. The question **is** related to vexing parse after all.

*I tried this on gcc-5.1.0 with --std=c++11*

Comment: I think it **is** related and allows `A a{int()};` but specifically not `A  a(int());`.

Comment: @Bo: The latter declares a member **function**, doesn't it?

Comment: @Ben - Yes, that's why it isn't used for initialization.  :-)  And also bans `A a(1);` because it invites the vexing parse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In-class initialization of non-static members was added after the brace syntax was introduced, and to avoid confusion such as most-vexing-parses, it was made to work only with the brace syntax for direct-initialization (copy initialization is also permitted).

The syntactic construct is named *brace-or-equal-initializer* (in C++11 and C++14, as chris notes in a comment, C++1z changes the name).

Comment: As of Kona, this was changed to [*default member initializer*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0134r0.html).